# R loop - Subset the file and run xlsx code

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, filter, xlsx

I have a dataframe which consists of 3 variables, one of the variables called staff contains 13 different staff groups and variable y is called countries which contains 10 countries which the staff  is in. Each country should be put into it's own excel workbook with the corresponding staff group. so I should have 13 x 10 permutations, I want an excel workbook for each country and I am using XLSX package to do so but I want to create a loop that filters the data by country and saves each country into it's own excel file so I don't have to replicate the code 10 times. My dataframe name is "Cost"

Below is my code that I have so far, I got no errors but I also get no output.

```
countries <- c("Ireland", "Scotland", "England", "Wales", "Germany", "Italy", "Russia", "Denmark", "USA", "Spain")

for(countriesb in countries){

#create excel output for each country
wb = createWorkbook(type="xlsx")

Costsheet = createSheet(wb, "Country")

Cost%>% filter(country==countriesb)

xlsx.addTitle<-function(sheet, rowIndex, title, titleStyle){
rows <-createRow(sheet,rowIndex=rowIndex)
sheetTitle <-createCell(rows, colIndex=1)
setCellValue(sheetTitle[[1,1]], title)
setCellStyle(sheetTitle[[1,1]], titleStyle)

TITLE_STYLE <- CellStyle(wb)+ Font(wb,  heightInPoints=16, 
                                   color="blue", isBold=TRUE, underline=0)

xlsx.addTitle(Cost, rowIndex=1, title="Cost",titleStyle = TITLE_STYLE)
addDataFrame(Cost, Costsheet, startRow =3, row.names=FALSE)

saveWorkbook(wb, "country.xlsx")

}
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting your workbook with each iteration.

Comment: Looking back, that is very obvious! Thanks. I am not getting any output at all, I would expect one output will that last country then?

Comment: You need to actually write the xlsx. Have a look at the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf)

Comment: That's what saveWorkbook does? This worked when I tested it for just 1 country and it gave me an output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following minimal example:

```
require("xlsx")

wb = createWorkbook(type="xlsx") #Create a workbook outside of the loop

x <- c("USA","UK","NL")

for(i in x){
    sh = createSheet(wb, as.character(i)) #Create Sheets inside the loop with corresponding x-values as sheet names
    addDataFrame(mtcars,sh, startRow =3, row.names=FALSE) # Add your data to the sheets
}

saveWorkbook(wb, "C:/YourPath/Yourfile.xlsx") # save your workbook outside the loop
```

Comment: Thanks, the logic makes sense. I will try apply it to my problem, I wanted separate workbooks for each country, not tabs.

Comment: is there a way to have a dynamic file name save for each country (e.g saveWorkbook(wb, x.xlsx") ?

Comment: use the `paste` function.

Comment: cheers! I found that out after some googling. I used file_name <- paste0("Name_", x,".xlsx") in case anyone else needed to know.